# Problem when trying to deploy war to Azure

Tags: azure, war, web-deployment

I tried to deploy a war file to Azure but failed, here's what I do.

First I tried to deploy the war by dragging the war file under `D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps` and then restarted the app service but the .war file didn't decompress.

Second I tried to deploy using power shell using these [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#deploy-war-file), but I got this error message:

`Invoke-RestMethod: You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`

Can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong!

By the way, I have web.config file under wwwroot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
         </requestFiltering>
      </security>
      <httpPlatform processPath="%AZURE_TOMCAT85_HOME%\bin\startup.bat"> <!-- arguments="-config D:\home\site\wwwroot\conf\server.xml start"> -->
         <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="CATALINA_OPTS" value="-Dport.http=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -Xms512m -Xmx2048m" />
            <environmentVariable name="CATALINA_HOME" value="%AZURE_TOMCAT85_HOME%" />
         </environmentVariables>
      </httpPlatform>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The war didn't decompress because tomcat is not running, so inside Application settings make sure that Java is activated and Java web container is Tomcat.

[image]

Also make sure that you have a deployement slot ( look the above pic ) if not create a new one.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great, it works using drag and drop war, but the powershell still showing the same error?